# R: Add count for unique values within Group, disregarding other variables within dataframe

Tags: r, group

I would like to add a new variable to my data frame, which, for each group says the number of unique entries with relation to one variable (state), while disregaring others.

Data input

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                 state=c("CT","CT","AK","TX","TX","AZ","GA","TX","WA"),
                 group=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                 age=c(12,33,57,98,45,67,16,85,22)
                 )
df
```

Desired output

```
want <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                 state=c("CT","CT","AK","TX","TX","AZ","GA","TX","WA"),
                 group=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                 age=c(12,33,57,98,45,67,16,85,22),
                 count=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
                 )
want
```

Comment: The  `count` in `want` only have `8` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need a group by `n_distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(count = n_distinct(state)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!!